# Not Certain Why CSS is Seemingly Unresponsive

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

Following along a tutorial when I got stuck with the CSS portion, the Wordpress site seems to be unresponsive to the changes I make in the CSS code. I'll post what I have:

//file abraham-admin.php

```
<h1>Abraham Theme Options</h1>
<?php settings_errors(); ?>
<?php 
    $firstName = esc_attr( get_option( 'first_name' ) );
    $lastName = esc_attr( get_option( 'last_name' ) );
    $fullName = $firstName . ' ' . $lastName;
    $description = esc_attr( get_option( 'user_description' ) );

?>
<div class="abraham-sidebar-preview">
    <div class="abraham-sidebar">
        <h1 class="abraham-username"><?php print $fullName ?></h1>
        <h2 class="abraham-description"><?php print $description ?></h2>
        <div class="icons-wrapper">

        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<form method="post" action="options.php" class="abraham-general-form">
    <?php settings_fields( 'abraham-settings-group'); ?>
    <?php do_settings_sections( 'z_abraham'); ?>
    <?php submit_button(); ?>
</form>
```

//file enqueue.php

```
function abraham_load_admin_scripts() {

    wp_register_style('abraham_admin', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/abraham_admin.css', array(), '1.0.0', 'all');
    wp_enqueue_style('abraham_admin');


}
add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'abraham_load_admin_scripts');
```

//file abraham_admin.css

```
.abraham-general-form,
.abraham-sidebar-preview { display: inline-blog; float: left; }

.abraham-sidebar-preview { width: 200px; background-color: #3f3f3f; padding: 20px; text-align: center; margin-right: 20px}
.abraham-sidebar { display: block; text-align: center; }
h1.abraham-username,
h2.abraham-description { font-weight: 100; color: #ffffff; }
h1.abraham-username { font-size: 24px; margin: 0 0 10px; }
h2.abraham-description { font-size: 13px; margin: 0 0 20px; }
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Looks good to me at first glance. If you open Chrome dev tools, can you see the CSS file being loaded as a **Source**?

Comment: Or check the dev tools and make sure cache is off or make your css files with timestamp i.e. site.com/style.css?ts=346357332

Comment: Have you tried clearing your browser cache ? or reload with ctrl+f5 , Use Browser inspectors to make sure your css file is loading correctly

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Really new to coding... I turned off my cache and it's still not doing anything different when I refresh the page. What would I be looking for to see if the CSS file is loaded as a Source?

Comment: Also, everything seems to work ok (I think) besides the color of the box.

Comment: So I changed the css file name to abraham.admin and altered accordingly. It updated to the new color I had in place. Weird! I guess that's how I'll go about updating the view of my css?

Comment: the best way to prevent the cache, it's calling the css with a timestamp, something like `wp_register_style('abraham_admin', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/abraham_admin.css?ts=[timestamp when you last modified the file]', array(), '1.0.0', 'all')`

Comment: http://shouldiblamecaching.com/

Comment: I've been trying to figure out the trick to putting in that timestamp, it's stressing me out way too much so I figured it'd just be best to surrender back to asking for help haha.